# Excel error on IF, `=IF(TRUE, 1, 2)` is invalid syntax?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I typed the following expression in a cell: `=IF(I2="N", J3, J4)`. Then Excels poped an error window telling the expression is invalid. The same error pops when I type `=IF(TRUE, 1, 2)` or `=IF(1=1, 1, 2)`. I'm an Excel begginner, and I'm sorry if the error is obvious but I just can't figure it out

Comment: Your `IF` expression looks valid to me.  Can you add any more information about the error?

Comment: Replace comma with a semi-colon > `=IF(I2="N";J3;J4)`

Comment: The comma semi-colon thing is down to your system settings - it’s not excel’s fault.

Comment: The semi-colon was the problem, thanks